# MySQL query, dealing with active and inactive products

Tags: mysql

Facing a problem and not getting the hint for a few hours. Maybe onyone can help me out.

Have the following query which shows the Topsellers. So the status of the product (active or not) is saved in b.Article_Status (0=inactive, 1=active).

How do I get the products of the result list which have no active product in the productfamily at the moment. But the product shall still be shown if an old one was ordered (and so is in table order_items) is now inactive and the active one was not ordered yet.

Actual query looks as follow. Already fund a solution which works when the actual active product has been ordered once, but still the problem with the mentioned case.

```
SELECT count( a.order_itemid ) AS numOrders, c.Product_ID, c.Product_Name, d.producer_name
FROM order_items a
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_article b ON b.Article_ID = a.order_itemid
LEFT OUTER JOIN product c ON b.Article_Productid = c.Product_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN producer d ON c.Product_Producer = d.producer_id
GROUP BY c.Product_ID
ORDER BY `numOrders` DESC
```

Comment: How are productfamilies defined?

Comment: you mean productcategories? Or the layout of article and product tables?

Comment: You said "productfamily" in your question; I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Ah, means entries in order_items but all articles in product_article are inactive for now (status = 0). I don't want to have those entries in the result list.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Perhaps you could show some example data and indicate what you'd like to see as the output?

Comment: Hmm okey.Table order_itmes a has only article IDs, Product ID is saved in Product Table. If I get everything out of the order table to generate topsellers I don't know if the article (different vintages) is still an active one. Stated in order_items three articles and I only want to show those ones with an active follow up article (both have the same ProductKey)

Comment: Find a solution with WHERE EXISTS, will post it as answer to my own question :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was a WHERE EXISTS subquery

```
SELECT count( a.order_itemid ) AS numOrders, c.Product_ID, c.Product_Name, d.producer_name
FROM order_items a
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_article b ON b.Article_ID = a.order_itemid
LEFT OUTER JOIN product c ON b.Article_Productid = c.Product_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN producer d ON c.Product_Producer = d.producer_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_article x WHERE c.Product_ID = x.Article_Productid AND x.Article_Status = 1)
GROUP BY c.Product_ID
ORDER BY `numOrders` DESC
LIMIT 5
```